# Use sendmail with Laravel 5 howto

Tags: laravel-5

I am wondering: How to use regular sendmail with Laravel 5. When I google this I get very little information. Who can help me out here?

My mailer script now uses gMail smtp and I would rather use sendmail:

```
    $send = Mail::send('emails.main', $data, function($message) use ($data) {
        $message->to($data['to']);
        $message->to($data['cc']);
        $message->subject($data['subject']);
    });
```

Comment: What OS are you on?  Do you have sendmail installed?  If you are on Windows here is an article that explains how to set it up: http://www.developerfiles.com/how-to-send-emails-from-localhost-apachephp-server/

Comment: I develop on Windows, but I want to set it up for an Ubuntu server (live environment). So I am not asking how to setup the server, but how to adjust config/mail.php

Comment: Hey @AlvinBakker did you figure it out? I´m with same issue here.

Comment: No I did not. We just changed to sendgrid and are using the API in combination with the Laravel plugin for it. That works like a charm